# Selector de Table com Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

Bom dia, tenho um trecho de código em Javascript que estou adicionando uma linha na tabela, porém quando implemento no sistema existe mais de uma tabela, precisaria especificar qual delas é com o id mas encontro dificuldades em colocar com o código.

```
$("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
```

é com isso que adiciono, gostaria de saber como colocar o id.

obrigado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Veja esse exemplo de como é passado o ID da tabela.
É simples mas é funcional.

```
<table id="tabela">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="opcao"></td>
    </tr>

</table>


    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#check').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var valido = true;

        $("#tabela tr").each(function(index, el) {
            var $linha = $(el);
            var checked = $linha.find('.opcao:checked').length;
            if (checked == 0 ) {
                valido = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        console.log('valido ' , valido);
        alert(valido ? 'checado' : 'erro');
    });
});
```